# yml worklfow issues using both github-hosted and self-hosted runners together for build and deployment

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I've been assigned the responsibility of managing the deployment process for our projects. To accomplish this, I've set up a self-hosted runner on a Digital Ocean server. Initially, the setup was designed solely to deploy code from GitHub to WPEngine. However, I've encountered challenges while attempting to integrate a build process into our workflow.

Initially, I configured the self-hosted runner to handle the build process, but it consistently failed. After extensive testing, we discovered that the build process worked smoothly when using a GitHub-hosted runner. As a workaround, I created a workflow that leverages the GitHub runner to build the project, followed by using artifacts to transfer the results from the GitHub runner to the self-hosted runner.

According to GitHub, these processes are running successfully up to a certain point. When I remove the /dist/ directory from the WPEngine environment and execute the build-deploy process, a new dist directory is generated on the server. However, there's an issue with CSS changes not being reflected.

To troubleshoot, I conducted a test. I copied the theme folder from the WPEngine Dev environment to our GitHub development repository. This WPEngine Dev environment represented the latest correct version of our project. Before running the build/deploy process, I removed the dist/ directory from the WPEngine project.

The expected outcome was that after pushing to GitHub, it would trigger the build process using the GitHub runner and then proceed to deploy using the self-hosted runner. However, the actual result was not as expected. The website displayed incorrect CSS, and changes previously applied to the WPEngine environment before this test are not reflected on the page.

here is the workflow:

```
name: Build and Deploy to  WPEngine
on:
  push:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
        working-directory: wp-content/themes/site

      - name: Build assets
        run: npm run build
        working-directory: wp-content/themes/site

      - name: Upload Build Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build-artifacts
          path: wp-content/themes/site/dist  

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download Build Artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build-artifacts
          path: wp-content/themes/site/dist  

      - name: GitHub Action Deploy to WP Engine Development env
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/development'
        uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
        with:
          WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE }}
          WPE_ENV: dev

      - name: GitHub Action Deploy to WP Engine Staging env
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
        with:
          WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE }}
          WPE_ENV: preview

      - name: GitHub Action Deploy to WP Engine Production env
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
        uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
        with:
          WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE }}
          WPE_ENV: site
```

after looking at the logs I found during the Build Assets part of the workflow:

```
Run npm run build

> wp@3.0.0 build /home/runner/work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run start -- build


> wp@3.0.0 start /home/runner/work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site
> gulp --gulpfile resources/build/gulp.js "build"

[21:45:45] Working directory changed to ~/work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/resources/build
[21:45:46] Using gulpfile ~/work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/resources/build/gulp.js
[21:45:46] Starting 'build'...
[21:45:46] Starting 'clean'...
[21:45:46] Finished 'clean' after 2.44 ms
[21:45:46] Starting 'styles'...

  Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist config.
  Use browserslist key in package.json or .browserslistrc file.

  Using browsers option can cause errors. Browserslist config 
  can be used for Babel, Autoprefixer, postcss-normalize and other tools.

  If you really need to use option, rename it to overrideBrowserslist.

  Learn more at:
  https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#readme
  https://twitter.com/browserslist


[21:45:49] Finished 'styles' after 3.04 s
[21:45:49] Starting 'scripts'...
(node:4235) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead. (Triggered by calling processImmediate on process.)
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[21:45:54] Version: webpack 4.47.0
Built at: 09/08/2023 9:45:54 PM
    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  345 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
Entrypoint main [big] = bundle.js

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  bundle.js (345 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (345 KiB)
      bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
[21:45:54] Finished 'scripts' after 5.77 s
[21:45:54] Starting 'images'...
[21:45:55] Finished 'images' after 578 ms
[21:45:55] Starting 'optimize'...
[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Gulp] /home/runner/work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Error running notifier] Could not send message: not found: notify-send
[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Gulp] write after end
[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Error running notifier] Could not send message: notify-send must be installed on the system.
[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Gulp] write after end
[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Error running notifier] Could not send message: notify-send must be installed on the system.
[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Gulp] write after end
[21:45:57] gulp-notify: [Error running notifier] Could not send message: notify-send must be installed on the system.
[21:45:58] Finished 'optimize' after 3.27 s
[21:45:58] Starting 'manifest'...
[21:45:58] Finished 'manifest' after 15 ms
[21:45:58] Finished 'build' after 13 s
```

here is an example of the yml when set to use the self-hosted runner for both tasks:

name: Build and Deploy to Site WPEngine
on:
push:
jobs:
build-deploy:
runs-on: self-hosted
steps:
- name: Checkout code
uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  - name: Set up Node.js
    uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: '12'

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: npm install
    working-directory: wp-content/themes/site  # Set the working directory

  - name: Build assets
    run: npm run build
    working-directory: wp-content/themes/site  # Set the working directory

  - name: GitHub Action Deploy to WP Engine Development env
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/development'
    uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
    with:
      WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE }}
      WPE_ENV: sitedev
    
  - name: GitHub Action Deploy to WP Engine Staging env
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
    uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
    with:
      WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE }}
      WPE_ENV: sitepreview
    
  - name: GitHub Action Deploy to WP Engine Production env
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    uses: wpengine/github-action-wpe-site-deploy@v3
    with:
      WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE: ${{ secrets.WPE_SSHG_KEY_PRIVATE }}
      WPE_ENV: site
```

when using this yml on the self-hosted runner it fails during the install dependency part. here is the log:

```
 Run npm install
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16: this package is now deprecated
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

> node-sass@4.14.1 install /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /home/ops/.npm/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1693258081388/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

> es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0


> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine

> gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@3.2.0 postinstall /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ jpegtran pre-build test passed successfully

> mozjpeg@4.1.1 postinstall /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/mozjpeg
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ The `/home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: autoreconf -fiv && ./configure --disable-shared --prefix="/home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --bindir="/home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --libdir="/home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" && make --jobs=1 && make install --jobs=1
Command failed: autoreconf -fiv
/bin/sh: 1: autoreconf: not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)

> optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ The `/home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
  ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at /home/ops/actions-runner/_work/site/site/wp-content/themes/site/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"12.22.12","npm":"6.14.16"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for triple-beam@1.4.1: wanted: {"node":">= 14.0.0"} (current: {"node":"12.22.12","npm":"6.14.16"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: triple-beam@1.4.1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN imports-loader@3.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN styled-components@5.3.11 requires a peer of react@>= 16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN styled-components@5.3.11 requires a peer of react-dom@>= 16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN wp@3.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN wp@3.0.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ops/.npm/_logs/2023-08-28T21_28_19_665Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've tried different Node versions. 12 and 14 are the ones that have gotten me the farthest but still, this is not working correctly.  Id love to just have this on the self-hosted runner but I can't figure out why it fails. Any help here would be appreciated.